# New approach to configure kube-proxy's proxymode in GKE/Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-proxy

I see a recent pull request was merged to remove the `net.experimental.kubernetes.io/proxy-mode` and `net.beta.kubernetes.io/proxy-mode` annotations.

My application's reverse proxy servers currently work much better when the proxymode is set to `userspace`, and I would like to keep using this setting after upgrading.

Since Google Container Engine hosts the Kubernetes master, and I cannot directly access that VM, how can I configure the kube-proxy proxymode without using annotations? Ideally I could change a cluster-wide setting so that new nodes (after autoscaling) also use the `userspace` proxy mode.